# How to slow-down bone animation through code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've drawn a tentacle on the screen with ik bones that I want to bend against the player when he's close enough. I have gotten this to work, but the animation is happening too fast,  and even though I throw all kinds of:

```
myMover.limitByTime = true;
myMover.timeLimit = 4000;
myMover.limitByIteration = true; 
myMover.iterationLimit = 1; 
myMover.limitByDistance = true
myMover.distanceLimit=1000;
```

code I think might slow it down, it doesn't slow down at all. How do I fix this? :S Im not sure if this is good form but I also have a somewhat related question: How do i get flash to recognize the armature if I don't have it set to runtime as opposed to authortime? Because if I set it to authortime then the following code returns null:

```
tentacle = IKManager.getArmatureByName("tentacle");
trace(tentacle);
```

Now the problem with runtime is that some clever users might be able to manipulate my tentaclemonster with the mouse :|

Comment: _"this might be a really easy question to answer but i dont want to spend more time on it."_ Then why should anyone here?

Comment: because to other people it might not be so difficult as it clearly is to me although i faintly suspect it is a easy question? I am sorry if i have offended, it was not my intention, but my head is full of muck.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the `IKMover` limits, they're intended to control maximum processing time, not the animation. You can adjust the speed of each bone by selecting it in the IDE and looking under the "Location" properties.

I'd suggest leaving the speed at 100% and removing the limits though, then animating the target point directly (and calling `moveTo` on each frame). That way you have more precise control over the speed.